# LWC Error on getting picklist values for specific recordTypeId

Tags: lightning-web-components, record-type

I'm getting an error every time I edit the Lightning Page layout. I'm not sure where or what I need to add to resolve it. I've done some googling and it's obviously related to something not being declared yet, but how do I fix it?

[image]

```
import { getObjectInfo, getPicklistValues } from "lightning/uiObjectInfoApi";
....
@api recordId;
@api objectApiName;

@track objectInfo;

@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: MY_OBJECT })
  objectInfo;
get recordTypeId() {
  // Returns a map of record type Ids
  console.log("get recordtype");
  const rtis = this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos;
  return Object.keys(rtis).find(
    (rti) => rtis[rti].name === "ABC Type"
 );
}
@wire(getPicklistValues, {
  recordTypeId: "$recordTypeId",
  fieldApiName: GENERATEREASON_FIELD
})
reasonPicklistValues;
....
```

I display the picklist values in my HTML, and use the recordType to create a new record.

```
createCertificate() {
  const fields = {};
  fields[ACCOUNT_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.acctid;
  fields[RECTTYPE_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.recordTypeId;
   .....
```

In my HTML I have a template which is displayed conditionally, and has a sub template which displays the picklist:

```
   <template if:true={reasonPicklistValues.data}>
      <lightning-combobox
          name="reason"
          label="Select a reason"
          value={value}
          placeholder="-Select-"
          options={reasonPicklistValues.data.values}
          onchange={handleChange}
          class="slds-var-m-around_x-small"
        >
     </lightning-combobox>
     <lightning-button
          variant="brand"
          label="Generate new record"
          title="Generate a new record from these details"
          onclick={createCertificate}
          class="slds-var-m-around_medium slds-align_absolute-center"
          disabled={isDisabled}
     ></lightning-button>
     .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are using getter to fetch the recordTypeId from objectinfo. The getter fires evreytime when property referenced in it gets changes and re-evaluates itself.

When you are editing the lightning page, `@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: MY_OBJECT })` experience change and getter fires to re-evaluate itself and find **objectInfo** does not hold any value.

You can make small change to check for undefined values in getter. It will make sure it does not throw any error even if the objectInfo property does not hold any value.

```
get recordTypeId() {
  if(this.objectInfo){
     if(this.objectInfo.data){
        if(this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos){
           const rtis = this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos;
           return Object.keys(rtis).find((rti) => rtis[rti].name === "ABC Type");
        }
     }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to store `objectInfo` from `wire` method and later to use it.

```
@track objectInfo;
    
@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: MY_OBJECT })
wiredRecord({ error,data }){
    if (data) {
        this.objectInfo = data;
    }
}


get recordTypeId() {
  // Returns a map of record type Ids
  console.log("get recordtype");
  const rtis = this.objectInfo.recordTypeInfos;
  return Object.keys(rtis).find(
    (rti) => rtis[rti].name === "ABC Type"
 );
}
```